# Problems proving a Lemma in the Fourier Analysis of piecewise-functions

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a Lemma, which is central in Fourier analysis of piece-wise function that I need to prove. I have proposed a proof, however it seems to be a little "shallow".

The Lemma is:

> The indicator functions $\chi_{A_j}(t)$(where ${A_j}$ is some interval $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$) and the piece-wise functions
> $f_n(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n\eta_j\chi_{A_j}(t)$ have the same Fourier
> coefficients on a uniform grid on the  interval  $[-a, a]$  for any
> $a$.

and my proposed proof:

*Take the $\alpha_k$ Fourier coefficient of an indicator function:
\begin{equation}
\beta_k=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^{a}\chi_{A_j}\sin k\omega t \text{d}t=\frac{1}{k \omega a}\chi_{A_j}\sin k \omega t \bigg|_{-a}^a=\frac{2}{k\pi}\chi_{A_j}\sin (k\pi)
\end{equation}
then we obtain a function independent of $a$. Hence, the Fourier coefficients are the same for any $a$, since they are independent of $a$.*

But it is too shallow. It needs more substance. I have no idea what. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What are $A_j$? As $A_j$ become more irregular, the functions might not even be integrable.

Comment: The title, and the tag, should give the reader some idea of what kind of mathematics is involved. Please edit them in accord with this requirement.

Comment: @GerryMyerson done. Riemann: Done too!

Comment: Well, half done. The tag, solution-verification, gives the reader no clue as to what branch of mathematics we are sealing with. Some users browse this site by tag, you know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Forgot that....